# Is there any opensource tool for loadtesting on SAP GUI Based applications?

Tags: load-testing

Do I know, whether any load testing tool is there for testing SAP GUI based applications?

I have been using Load Runner as of now, but the license is going to expire soon. So, I am in a position to find the better replacement for the same.

Responses are appreciated :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are no open source tools for testing SAPGUI applications.  Architecturally, none of the existing open source applications have hooks to the automation interface used by SAP.  So, you may discount the previous answer which concentrates on web-based interfaces or a generic TCP interface.   The interface for SAPGUI automation is on the client.

SAPWeb, on the other hand, may be tackled with standard commercial and open source solutions which architecturally support the capture, modification and reproduction of traffic at the HTTP protocol layer.

Renew your LoadRunner license.  The cost in hours of labor to modify any of the available open source tools will more than exceed the cost of your LoadRunner license.  You will need to establish a relationship with SAP for the interface documentation.  You will need to build a recording interface and a playback interface. You can look to the R&D output from the big vendors, HP, Borland, IBM, to see what a non trivial and high engineering dollar challenge this is.